# Type Promise<any> have no call signatures

Tags: typescript

I want to return an async function after 300ms.

In order to do that I thought about creating a promise which I resolve after 300 ms

```
const justLogDataFromForms = async (index, key, currentValue, payload) => {

      const  dummyPromise:Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(true);
        }, 300);
      });
   await dummyPromise()
return 
}
```

but this throws error

> Type Promise have no call signatures.

Can someone explain me the error and let me know how I can fix it? Also, is there a better way to return an async function after x amount of time after it is called?

Comment: `await dummyPromise()` is trying to _call_ something you just typed (and created!) as a _promise_, which indeed isn't callable.

Comment: Just get rid of the parens in your await

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `dummyPromise` is a **Promise** and not a **Function** so it can not be called. Just remove the parenthesis to await the Promise or don't use a variable at all:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
    }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
await Promise.all([dummyPromise]);
```

This should work in some case that really need `Promise` as variable(s).